# VBScript summation

Tags: vbscript

I have this code that is trying to show the summation of;

- All the even numbers from 0-100 or whatever number the user inputs

and then;

- Show the summation of all the odd numbers from 0-100 or whatever number the user inputs.

Here is what I have so far:

```vb
Evennumber=InputBox("Please enter a even number!")

print "total + e"

For e= 2 to Evennumber step 2
  total= total+e
  print total&" +  "&e
Next

print total


Oddnumber=InputBox("Please enter a odd number!")
print "total + o"

For o= 1 to Oddnumber step 2
  total = total + o
  print total&" + "&o 
Next

print total
```

Is this correct?

Comment: You'd need to make `total` equal to 0 before the second summation.

Answer (score 1):

The key point is you didn't initialize `total` to zero before using it.

```vb
Option Explicit
Dim e, o, Evennumber, Oddnumber, total

Evennumber = InputBox("Please enter a even number!")

MsgBox "total + e"

total = 0
For e = 2 to Evennumber step 2
  total= total+e
  MsgBox total & " +  " & e
Next
MsgBox total

Oddnumber = InputBox("Please enter a odd number!")
MsgBox "total + o"

total = 0
For o = 1 to Oddnumber step 2
  total = total + o
  MsgBox total & " + " & o 
Next
MsgBox total
```

Comment: Actually, it's not necessary to initialize variables in VBScript, they'll be by default 0 or empty string. But  it's indeed a best practice.

Comment: @montonero yes but iBug is making the point that on the second `For` loop the `total` needs to be reinitialised to 0.

Comment: @Lankymart yeah, I've made the same comment under OP's post :)

Answer (score 1):

[@iBug's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54196177/692942) is correct but it fails to point out key programming principles that you should try to follow that will benefit you in the long run. This example focuses on [DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) which if implemented would have made the re-set of `total` to zero a moot point.

Both processes of selecting a number and looping through the numbers by value are almost identical. When you have code like this, the best approach is to build a Function or Sub Procedure to handle the logic without requiring it to be duplicated.

Below we use a Sub Procedure called `ProcessNumbers()` and pass whether we want Even or Odd that way with a little initial setup we can use the same function to process both sets of numbers.

```
Option Explicit

'Even
Call ProcessNumbers(True)
'Odd
Call ProcessNumbers(False)

Sub ProcessNumbers(isEven)
  Dim i, startFrom, endAt, total, label
  Dim input, criteria

  If isEven Then 
    startFrom = 2
    endAt = 100
    label = "Even"
  Else
    startFrom = 1
    endAt = 100
    label = "Odd"
  End If
  input = InputBox("Please enter an " & label & " number!")
  If Len(input & "") > 0 And IsNumeric(input) Then endAt = CLng(input)
  For i = startFrom To endAt
    If isEven Then criteria = (i Mod 2 = 0) Else criteria = (i Mod 2 <> 0)
    If criteria Then
      total = total + i
      WScript.Echo total & " + " & i
    End If
  Next
  WScript.Echo total
End Sub
```

Output:

```
2 + 2
6 + 4
12 + 6
20 + 8
30 + 10
42 + 12
56 + 14
72 + 16
90 + 18
110 + 20
132 + 22
156 + 24
182 + 26
210 + 28
240 + 30
272 + 32
306 + 34
342 + 36
380 + 38
420 + 40
462 + 42
506 + 44
552 + 46
600 + 48
650 + 50
702 + 52
756 + 54
812 + 56
870 + 58
930 + 60
992 + 62
1056 + 64
1122 + 66
1190 + 68
1260 + 70
1332 + 72
1406 + 74
1482 + 76
1560 + 78
1640 + 80
1722 + 82
1806 + 84
1892 + 86
1980 + 88
2070 + 90
2162 + 92
2256 + 94
2352 + 96
2450 + 98
2550 + 100
2550
1 + 1
4 + 3
9 + 5
16 + 7
25 + 9
36 + 11
49 + 13
64 + 15
81 + 17
100 + 19
121 + 21
144 + 23
169 + 25
196 + 27
225 + 29
256 + 31
289 + 33
324 + 35
361 + 37
400 + 39
441 + 41
484 + 43
529 + 45
576 + 47
625 + 49
676 + 51
729 + 53
784 + 55
841 + 57
900 + 59
961 + 61
1024 + 63
1089 + 65
1156 + 67
1225 + 69
1296 + 71
1369 + 73
1444 + 75
1521 + 77
1600 + 79
1681 + 81
1764 + 83
1849 + 85
1936 + 87
2025 + 89
2116 + 91
2209 + 93
2304 + 95
2401 + 97
2500 + 99
2500
```

Comment: Although I totally agree with DRY approach, in some cases it could be not worth to use it due to an increased time consumption and code complexity. This case is a pretty good example: your code is more universal and robust, but it's way more complicated as the OP's code (which is almost correct and working).

Comment: @montonero tried to keep it simple and not diverge too much but appreciate the feedback.